# How to load properties table of topojson in R as a dataframe?

Tags: r, properties, rstudio, topojson, geojsonio

I'm trying to read the properties table into r as a dataframe.

I'm using geojsonio.

`library('geojsonio')`

Then I load my topojson file.

`house_map <- topojson_read("./tl_2016_us_cd115/tl_2016_us_cd115_simplify.topojson")`

That is all good.

Now I have a values object that looks like this.

But I don't understand how to load the properties object of the topojson.

Tips?

Comment: late to the party .... what properties are you talking about? `topojson_read` returns a `sp` style class object - you can access various part of it like `x@foobar`

Comment: Write-up here on the properties attribute in geojson/topojson https://macwright.org/2015/03/23/geojson-second-bite @sckott

Comment: it's pulled out into the `data` slot, e.g., `file <- system.file("examples/swiss_cantons.topojson", package = "geojsonio"); x <- topojson_read(file); x@data`

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience, it is totally possible to do that using `rgdal` package.

Here is a post that talks about it: https://lincolnmullen.com/blog/topojson-in-r-with-rgdal/

For example, this works:

```
nycounties <- rgdal::readOGR("json/nycounties.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON")
```

I am not really an expert but this topic is quite specialized and I had to read a lot from different parts to solve this in the past.